# How do I drill a long hole lengthwise all the way through a post to make a standing lamp?

Tags: wood, hole, post

I have a beautiful post of reclaimed wood and I'd like to make it into a lamp. Not sure how to do this but I know the first step is to drill a hole all the way through it lengthwise. What is the tool and technique for this job and might I find a woodshop that could help me with it?

Comment: Probably a drill press, but that would work only if you have a bit long enough that won't deviate too much. How long and wide is the post?

Answer (score 5):

Long (18" and longer) drill bits do exist. If the hole is wide enough, bit extensions are also usable.

However, there's also a simple-but-elegant cheat. Cut the piece lengthwise, rout a channel in one or both sides, glue back together. If you make a thin-kerf cut, and are careful during reassembly, the glue line can be nearly invisible -- especially on straight-grained wood with the cut aligned with the grain lines.

Comment: +1 When I read the question, splitting the post immediately came to mind, and, lo and behold, you answered it!

Comment: For the kerf to be thin enough, would you have to use a band saw, or are there other options?  Seems like even a thin-kerf table saw blade would be too much.

Comment: If you're cutting generally with the grain dividing and reassembling is surprisingly forgiving.

Comment: My thoughts were somewhere between this and taking a notch out of the backside (towards wall) putting wires in the trough then covering with scrap wood to match. Since yours is a more likely method I'll upvote and just comment.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the diameter and length. You may be able to use a conventional type bit and go half way from each end; I have made about 16" hole in 2" diameter that way . An expensive alternative is a gun drill (bit); it does not have spiral flutes and only cuts on one side of the point , and it can drill gun barrels. If the diameter is "large", a auger bit may do it, they make a pretty straight hole , but I never used on for this.